# Can't load local script with NextJs "beforeInteractive" strategy

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

i'm using Nextjs `"next": "14.1.0"` for a project, i need to load a script that sets some window variables the script just does this:

```
//config.js

window.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_ENV = "development"
window.REACT_APP_VENDOR = "some-vendor-name"
```

i try to load it in the RootLayout with the beforeInteractive strategy

```
    <html lang={locale}>
      <body
        className={cn(
          "min-h-screen bg-background font-primary text-primary antialiased",
        )}
      >
        <Script
          id="config-variables"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
          src="/scripts/config.js"
        />
            {children}
      </body>
    </html>
```

the script sits in the public/scripts directory but it just doesn't get loaded in the head tag..in fact it doesn't get loaded at all (though i can see it's being downloaded in the network tab)!

is this a bug or am i doing something wrong ?

i tried followind the docs nothing worked though

Answer (score 0):

Suggested adding it to the **"_app.js"** file.

```
export default function App() {

  const AddedScript = () => {
    // Create a script element
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `/scripts/config.js`;
    script.id = `config-variables`;
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.setAttribute('strategy', 'beforeInteractive');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    AddedScript();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    ...
    </>
  );
}
```